# console.log me muestra otro valor de mi variable!

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un problema muy raro. En mi BD tengo un campo llamado "VPXBARRA" junto con varios otros como VCLIENTE o VFACTURA. El asunto es que, por ejemplo, una fila de la barra trae el valor de 0801010 y mediante el ALERT o CONSOLE.LOG cambia a 801010. Otra fila por ejemplo cambia de 0207102 a 69186. Solo pasa con esta columna porque VCLIENTE o VFACTURA se mantiene igual[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito el valor que aparece en la BD para poder eliminar su registro.

Cuando hago un ECHO de la barra, me aparece el valor normal. El problema solo ocurre con script

Este es mi codigo

```
    mysql_select_db($bd,$con);

//Selecciona una compra especifica por RUT y FACTURA desde otro formulario
$sql = "SELECT * FROM compra WHERE VCLIENTE =".$_GET['cliente']." AND VFACTURA =".$_GET['factura'];

$res=mysql_query($sql,$con);

 ?>
```

La tabla de los datos

```
<table id="tresult" class="table table-striped  table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" style="width: auto; margin-top: 40px;" >
            <thead>
                <tr><th colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">Vista de compra</th></tr>
                <tr style="background-color:#999999; color:white; font-weight:bold">
                    <th class="th-sm">Barra</th>
                    <th class="th-sm">Descripcion</th>
                    <th class="th-sm">Fecha</th>
                    <th class="th-sm">Proveedor</th>
                    <th class="th-sm"></th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
               <?php
              if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
                        ?> <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">No hay resultados</td>
               <?php 
               } else {
                while ($fila=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

                ?>

                <td><?php echo $fila['VPXBARRA']; ?></td>

                    <td width="800"><div align="left"><?php echo $fila['VPXNOM'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila['VFECHA']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila['VCLIENTE'];  ?></td>
                    <td><td><a href="javascript:confirmarEliminacion(<?= $fila['VPXBARRA'];?>,<?= $fila['VFACTURA'];?>)" class='btn btn-danger' title='Eliminar producto <?php echo $fila["VPXBARRA"];?> de la compra<?php echo $fila["VFACTURA"];?>'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></td><tr>
                <?php } }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

En la parte del botón eliminar, donde aparece "title", efectivamente aparece el valor normal, pero envia como parametro el valor cambiado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parte de JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function confirmarEliminacion(barra, factura){
    var f = factura;
    var b = barra;
    console.log(barra);
    var direccion;

    direccion = "removecompra.php?barra="+b+"&factura="+f;
    eliminar=confirm("¿Deseas eliminar la compra seleccionada?");
    if (eliminar) {
        window.location.href = direccion; 
    }
    else {
        alert('Error al eliminar el registro seleccionado');
    }
}
</script>
```

Aca otro console.log para notar la diferencia entre lo que muestra en barra y factura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta agregar comillas asi: `<a href="javascript:confirmarEliminacion('<?= $fila['VPXBARRA'];?>',...`

Comment: no va en la pregunta, pero trata de cambiar la solicitud de eliminar el metodo

Comment: Si estas usando bootstrap, quiero suponer que usas también Jquery. No entiendo por que estás metiendo N número de funciones al DOM si con una sola puedes hacer los enlaces de datos dinámicos. La respuesta de alanfcm es correcta... parsea el valor a un string para que no cambie.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript está tomando el numero `0207102` como si fuera un numero octal, es por eso que cuando lo mandas a la consola te da otro numero... ese otro numero es el *numero decimal*. Debido a que no estas haciendo ninguna operacion matematica con ese numero, lo mejor es que hagas como dice @alanfcm, daselo a la funcion `confirmarEliminacion(` como si fuera una cadena:

Cambia la linea:

```
<td><td><a href="javascript:confirmarEliminacion(<?= $fila['VPXBARRA'];?>,<?= $fila['VFACTURA'];?>)" class='btn btn-danger' title='Eliminar producto <?php echo $fila["VPXBARRA"];?> de la compra<?php echo $fila["VFACTURA"];?>'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></td><tr>
```

por

```
<td><td><a href="javascript:confirmarEliminacion('<?= $fila['VPXBARRA'];?>','<?= $fila['VFACTURA'];?>')" class='btn btn-danger' title='Eliminar producto <?php echo $fila["VPXBARRA"];?> de la compra<?php echo $fila["VFACTURA"];?>'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></td><tr>
```

Y debería de funcionar, pues ya no es un numero octal, ahora es una cadena de caracteres.